# MySQL OUTER JOIN syntax error

Tags: mysql, syntax, outer-join

Maybe a facepalm for you guys, but as a SQL query newbie, I'm having a syntax issue. Anyone know what's wrong?

```
SELECT * FROM company C
OUTER JOIN company_address A ON C.company_id = A.company_id
WHERE A.company_id IS NULL
```

Giving the error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'OUTER JOIN company_address A ON C.company_id = A.company_id WHERE A.address_id 
' at line 2
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[In MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. There is no just `OUTER JOIN`. If you need `FULL OUTER JOIN` in MySql [you can use `UNION` of `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Comment: @philipxy fair enough, I just found it hard to parse ("to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it"), but I didn't consider that could be just me.  Good feedback, thank you.

Comment: @lewis Unfortunately a lot of site protocols/conventions/policies are poorly documented. (Also there is not always consensus.) For site use Q&A google [meta] & [meta.se] via 'site:'.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM company C
LEFT JOIN company_address A ON C.company_id = A.company_id
WHERE A.company_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write LEFT JOIN,RIGHT JOIN,INNER JOIN or FULL OUTER JOIN instead of only **OUTER JOIN**.

There is also one error with your table name there shouldn't be **space** between the letters of a table like this [**company C**- it should be named as **company_C**]

I hope that will be work..All the best!

Comment: C is alias of Company, and it does not mean the name of the table.